# How to query Oracle SQL using FOR LOOP and get table returned?

Tags: sql, oracle

Our company is using Oracle 11g (11.2.0.5.0)

I'm looking for a way to execute external query (in this specific example called from PHP website) that would FOR LOOP through set of data and return results in the form of table (like normal SELECT would)

`USERS` table:

```
DB1
DB2
DB3
...
DBO
```

Each user's schema contains `ITEM` table:

```
ID     CODE     TYPE
--------------------
1      0001     A
2      0043     A
3      00A5     V
...
```

I want to execute a query that would loop through all `USERS` and fetch data from their `ITEM` tables, something along lines of my not working

```
FOR user IN (SELECT * FROM all_users)
LOOP
   SELECT CODE, user FROM user.ITEM_TABLE WHERE TYPE = 'V'
END LOOP;
```

That would return

```
CODE     USER
-------------
00A5     DB1
0434     DB2
0999     DB2
...
```

Comment: are u using sql server or oracle? (your caption and description mismatches!)

Comment: What is the relation between `User_table` and `Item_table` and definitely you don't need **LOOP** for this

Comment: I'm using
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: It's not `User_table`, it's `all_users` table (I guess it's not a table technically). Tables `Item_table` are inside each user's personal tables.

Comment: I've corrected code, it should be user.ITEM_TABLE, now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your need, maybe this can help:

```
declare
    type tabUser is table of varchar2(30);
    type tabCode is table of varchar2(30);
    vTabCode tabCode;
    vTabUser tabUser;
    vSQL varchar2(32767);
begin

    select listagg('select code, ''' || owner || ''' from ' || owner || '.item_table where type = ''V''', ' UNION ALL ')
    within group (order by owner)
    into vSQL
    from dba_tables where table_name = 'ITEM_TABLE';
    --
    dbms_output.put_line(vSQL);
    --
    execute immediate vSQl bulk collect into vTabCode, vTabUser;
    --
    /* ... what you need to do with your data */
end;
/
```

I removed all_users, given that probably there are users that do not have the `ITEM_TABLE` table, for example `SYS`; in this way you only query for really existing tables.

The first part dynamically builds the query you need, by concatenating queries from different users; in the second part you have your data extracted from all the tables, so you can do whatever you need.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, but isn't this solution limited to 32767 rows?

Comment: 32767 is only the limit to the size of dynamic string; if you need more, have a look at CLOB

Comment: Thanks. Now let's say I just want the script to return all collected data. How would I do that in your example?

Comment: If you need a function or procedure returning data, you can use OUT parameters; if you simply need to print results, you can loop through the data structures `vTabCode`and `vTabUser` and print their content with `DBMS_OUTPUT`.